# CircleCI Error migrating config to version 2

Tags: migration, bitbucket, circleci, migrating

I am trying to migrating circleci 1.0 to 2.0 ,
and I got this error.
***in job ‘build’: steps is not a list***
can someone help me what is the reason ?

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.2.3-jessie
    environment:
      AWS_REGION: eu-central-1
    steps:
        - checkout
        - run: echo "Tests are skipped because of static site."
        - run: mkdir -p /tmp/test-data

deploy:
  production:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - bundle exec middleman s3_sync
```

Comment: I tried the config and did not have any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

The identation of the array below `steps` seems to be off. Try this:

```
steps:
  - checkout
  - run: echo "Tests are skipped because of static site."
  - run: mkdir -p /tmp/test-data
```